# Mysql php querying improvement over SELECT star...beginner easy

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with following fields:

```
ID,tomato1,tomato2,tomato3
```

`tomato1,2,3` are text columns.
Each `tomato1` entry is unique, ID is autoincrement int, everything else is VARCHAR
I am given tomato1 only.

I am using the query:

```
SELECT * WHERE tomato1='whatever'
```

I hear some people on the internet who say don't use `SELECT *` so I want to ask, Is this a bad way to do this?  IS there a more efficient query code/method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asterisk means that you're always selecting all the columns from this table.  So if you only want the entry of tomato3, your query should read : `SELECT tomato3 FROM tomatoes WHERE tomato1='whatever'`

Comment: I see I think.  My goal is:  Given tomato1 to return tomato2 and tomato3.  so is : SELECT tomato2 and tomato3 FROM table1 WHERE tomato1='whatever' correct?

Comment: `SELECT tomato2, tomato3 FROM table1 WHERE tomato1 = 'whatever'` (no `AND` in your select clause, just comma separated)

Answer (score 0):

Generally just query for data you need, because it limits amount of transmitted data, so `SELECT ID, tomato2, tomato3 WHERE tomato1 = 'whatever'` might be better.

Answer (score 0):

It's mainly down to retrieving more data than is required, and thus a performance hit. Do you use the data from all of the columns?
It could help with code maintance too, as you are explicitly calling everything rather than a generic '*'.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if you change your table in the future, and your application is expecting only the fields that exist today, SELECT * will bring fields the application doesn't expect.
SELECT with named fields is more mantainable.